# Identify partial duplicates in 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
var items = [['892','NEW','blue'],
         ['341','USED','red'],
         ['892','NEW','yellow'],
         ['121','USED','blue'],
         ['735','NEW','red'],
         ['121','NEW','blue'],
         ['121','USED','yellow']];
```

Each item has 3 elements. If the exact combination of the first 2 elements of an item occurs elsewhere in the array then I need to output those 2 elements. So in this case the desired output should be:

```
output = [['892','NEW'],
          ['121','USED]];
```

Comment: I've been tinkering with code that is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035885/function-to-return-distinct-values-in-a-2d-array but I haven't been able to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powerful and simple:

```js
var items = [['892','NEW','blue'],
         ['341','USED','red'],
         ['892','NEW','yellow'],
         ['892','NEW','yellow'],
         ['892','NEW','yellow'],
         ['121','USED','blue'],
         ['735','NEW','red'],
         ['121','NEW','blue'],
         ['121','USED','yellow']];
var output = [];
var spotted = {};


items.map(function(el){
    var string = ''+el[0]+el[1];
    if(spotted[string] === 0){ 
       output.push([el[0],el[1]]);
       spotted[string] = 1;
    }else if(spotted[string] != 1) spotted[string] = 0;
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: You're going to get duplicates if the same subarray occurs 3 or more times.

Comment: Same problem. Actually test it with a bunch of duplicates.

Comment: Your syntax is off. The way you're writing it is a self increment and an assignment on the same line. I'm surprised js doesn't throw an error. You're looking for this: `spotted[string] += (typeof spotted[string] == "number") ? 1 : 0` edit: never mind, you'd have to add another line of code before this in order to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Here would be my implementation. I create a set to keep track of the elements I've already seen. If it exists in that set, then I add it to a different set of duplicates. Unfortunately, you can't perform equality checks on objects, so I convert the elements into a string first. I use a `Set` as my data structure because they never have duplicates.

Then after everything is done, I turn the set into an array and map over it to create the original arrays.

```js
const items = [['892','NEW','blue'],
            ['341','USED','red'],
            ['892','NEW','yellow'],
            ['121','USED','blue'],
            ['735','NEW','red'],
            ['121','NEW','blue'],
            ['121','USED','yellow']]

    const duplicates = new Set
    const check = new Set
    items.forEach(([num, status, color]) => {
      let combined = [num, status].join(",")
      if (check.has(combined)) {
        duplicates.add(combined)
      } else {
        check.add(combined)
      }
    })
    const duplicatedArr = Array.from(duplicates).map(strArr => strArr.split(","))
console.log(duplicatedArr)
```

Comment: Andrew, I'm trying to include this in a Google Apps script as well, and the line items.forEach(([num, status, color]) => { 
throws a syntax error there.

Comment: @dean2020 You might need a transpiler in order to use that syntax I use, like babel. Do you know how to write it in a ES5 way?

Comment: @Andrew, since the code posted works in Google Apps I'll use that one for now. Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash table for same first two elements of the array and count them. If found exactly two filter that element. After fultering map just the first two elements.

```js
var items = [['892', 'NEW', 'blue'], ['341', 'USED', 'red'], ['892', 'NEW', 'yellow'], ['121', 'USED', 'blue'], ['735', 'NEW', 'red'], ['121', 'NEW', 'blue'], ['121', 'USED', 'yellow']],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = items
        .filter(function (a) {
            var key = a.slice(0, 2).join('|');
            hash[key] = (hash[key] || 0) + 1;
            return hash[key] === 2;
        })
        .map(function (a) {
            return a.slice(0, 2);
        });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var items = [
  ['892', 'NEW', 'blue'],
  ['341', 'USED', 'red'],
  ['892', 'NEW', 'yellow'],
  ['121', 'USED', 'blue'],
  ['735', 'NEW', 'red'],
  ['121', 'NEW', 'blue'],
  ['121', 'USED', 'yellow']
];

var out = [];
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  for (j = i + 1; j < items.length; j++) {
    if (items[i][0] === items[j][0] && items[i][1] === items[j][1]) {
      out.push([items[i][0], items[i][1]]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(out);
```